# Get values of array in an array with one foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to get the values of an array inside an array but I couldn't make it work. This is what I tried.

```
for($i=2;$i<=$row_count;$i++){
    $auto_part = 'auto_part'.$i;
    $auto_parts['part'][] = $_POST[$auto_part];
    $description = 'auto_description'.$i;
    $auto_parts['description'][] = $_POST[$description];
}
foreach($auto_parts as $part){
    echo $part['part'];
    echo $part['description'];
}
```

The for loop is right and the array is build up the way I want too I checked that. But how can I get both arrays of $part['part'] and $part['description'] in one foreach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structure your array differently if the data is related

```
for($i=2; $i<=$row_count; $i++){
    $auto_part = 'auto_part' . $i;
    $description = 'auto_description' . $i;
    $auto_parts[] = array(
        'part' => $_POST[$auto_part],
        'description' => $_POST[$description]
    );
}
foreach($auto_parts as $part){
    echo $part['part'];
    echo $part['description'];
}
```

Comment: I would also consider not creating $auto_part and $description and just access $_POST directly.

Comment: Why count auto parts every time? Why not a counter or something?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with PHP. I restructured the code after I looked at it for a while longer and realized my stupidity

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach($variable as $key => $value)`

```
for($i=2;$i<=$row_count;$i++){
    $auto_part = 'auto_part'.$i;
    $auto_parts['part'][] = $_POST[$auto_part];
    $description = 'auto_description'.$i;
    $auto_parts['description'][] = $_POST[$description];
}
foreach($auto_parts as $key => $part){
    echo $part['part'][$key];
    echo $part['description'][$key];
}
```